# DateFields not using custom DATE_FORMAT for output

Tags: python, django

I've followed [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#date-format) in order to set the date output format for all the `DateField`s used in my project.

Despite this, dates are still not being rendered in the format I'm enforcing. They're being outputted as `YYYY-mm-dd` instead.

Here's my config:

#### settings.py

```
USE_L10N = False

DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%d/%m/%Y', # '25/10/2006'
]
```

Is there something I'm missing here, or is this a bug with Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of FunkyBob on IRC, the issue has been resolved.

I was using a custom widget for my `DateField`s:

```
class CalendarWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('main/js/vendor/pickadate.js-3.5.6/lib/compressed/themes/default.css',
                    'main/js/vendor/pickadate.js-3.5.6/lib/compressed/themes/default.date.css',)
        }
        js = ('main/js/vendor/pickadate.js-3.5.6/lib/compressed/picker.js',
              'main/js/vendor/pickadate.js-3.5.6/lib/compressed/picker.date.js',
              'main/js/datepicker.min.js',)
```

I simply had to use `forms.DateInput` instead of `forms.TextInput` in order for it to output my dates in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying how the template engine should format your variable? You need to add the `date` tag where you output your variable in the template.

[From the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

> If value is a datetime object (e.g., the result of datetime.datetime.now()), the output will be the string 'Wed 09 Jan 2008'.
>
> When used without a format string, the DATE_FORMAT format specifier is used. Assuming the same settings as the previous example:
>
> [...]

Meaning you have to do something like this:

```
{{ my_variable|date }}
```

Comment: This isn't for a variable, it's for `DateField`s in one of my forms.

Comment: How do you use the variable? Is the form an admin form or do you build your own forms. You only said "rendered" in your question, so I assumed you ment in the template file.

Comment: I was rendering the field in a template using `{{ form.field_name }}`

Comment: Then use `{{ form.field_name|date }}`

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you could do that when rendering fields